# Trying to Store slice (Array) in 2d Slice (array) in Recursion

Tags: go

Trying to perform combination sum problem through recursion and finding subsequences and storing subsequences slice (array) in 2D slice (array) in recursion but after execution getting null 2D slice. For combination sum problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/)

Through the map it's possible but I wanted to know how we can do same with the help of 2D Slice (array) [][]int

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
        sourceArr := []int{4, 8, 10, 17, 1, 2, 7}
        subSeq := make([]int, 0, len(sourceArr))
        arrayOfArr := make([][]int, 0)
        // i'm calling fuction passing the arguments
        FindCombinationV2(sourceArr, subSeq, 10, 0, arrayOfArr)
        //after execution i'm getting null array's in 2D array
        fmt.Printf("arrayOfArr: %v\n", arrayOfArr)
    }
    func FindCombinationV2(arr, subSequenceArr []int, target, index int, ans [][]int) {
        if index == len(arr) {
            if target == 0 {
                // i'm getting sub sequences of actual target sum
                // here i'm appending subSequence slice in ans 2D slice
                ans = append(ans, [][]int{subSequenceArr}...)
            }
            return
        }
        if target >= arr[index] {
            subSequenceArr = append(subSequenceArr, arr[index])
            FindCombinationV2(arr, subSequenceArr, target-arr[index], index, ans)
            subSequenceArr = subSequenceArr[:len(subSequenceArr)-1]
        }
    
        FindCombinationV2(arr, subSequenceArr, target, index+1, ans)
    
    }
```

Comment: Probably related: [Combination Sum in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158984/combination-sum-in-go)

Comment: One problem you have is that you always lose the value of `ans`.  Maybe either return it from `FindCombinationV2` or make it a pointer parameter. 
If you do the latter, your `append` statement will need to look like `*ans = append(*ans, ...)`